# Disable Blinking cursor in Pantheon Terminal

Tags: pantheon-terminal, gnome-terminal

I cannot figure out how to disable the blinking cursor is Pantheon-Terminal (which I think is the same as Gnome-Terminal). I looked in dconf-editor, but did not see any variable that seemed to be about blinking.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Pantheon Terminal uses the VTE widget kit and can be customized via the dconf registry. You can turn off the blinking with dconf-editor under `org.gnome.desktop.interface` or via the command line:

```
 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-blink false
```

and turn back on with

```
 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-blink true
```

or

```
 gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-blink
```

You can play with other settings to the cursor as well under `org.gnome.desktop.interface` (`cursor-theme`, `cursor-blink-time`, `cursor-size`, etc. keys).

Comment: Can you accept the answer as well, please?